# Can somebody tell me HOW dartlang instances abstract Map class?

Tags: java, dart

Why is dart's hashmap not like java's hashmap?

Meaning that the hashmap of java is

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {}
```

But dart is

```
abstract class HashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {}
```

Why is it `abstract`?

!!!New Question!!!

1. How would I know which child class extends "abstract class HashMap"?
2. My other question is that since abstract class HashMap implements Map interface, it does not implement 
   `void clear()`
   function. I wonder where the `void clear()` function of the Map interface is implemented? I cannot find it in abstract HashMap class.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not familiar with Dart, but I suppose it's *a completely different programming language* which compiles into JS. It's no surprise developers implement some programming concepts similarly (sometimes, identically) in their languages/libraries.

Comment: "!!!New Question!!!" Post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest! I have post it as a new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647701/can-somebody-answer-me-a-dart-question-about-hashmap

Answer (score 1):

In Dart you can have a concrete `factory` constructor on an `abstract` class and forward to another class. Although the constructor is called against the abstract class, the instance you get is of a concrete subtype.

```
abstract class Foo {
  factory Foo() = Bar;
}

class Bar implements Foo {}

void main() {
  print(Foo().runtimeType); // "Bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
external factory HashMap(
      {bool equals(K key1, K key2),
      int hashCode(K key),
      bool isValidKey(potentialKey)});
```

The factory constructor returns the instance of `_HashMap`.

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var hashMap = HashMap();
  print(hashMap.runtimeType);
}
```

Result:

`_HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`

Which means that `_HashMap` implements (or extends) `HashMap`.