# Can somebody answer me a Dartlang question about HashMap?

Tags: dart

The old question in 
[Can somebody tell me HOW dartlang instances abstract Map class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636359/can-somebody-tell-me-how-dartlang-instances-abstract-map-class?noredirect=1#comment97982339_55636359)

1. How would I know which child class extends "abstract class Map"?
2. My other question is that since abstract class HashMap implements Map interface, it does not implement  `void clear()` function. I wonder where the `void clear()` function of the Map interface is implemented? I cannot find it in abstract HashMap class.

Comment: HashMap extends AbstractMap class and implements Map interface. The clear() that you’re talking about, comes from the AbstractMap class. This particular clear() function calls entrySet().clear().

Comment: Hi @HarshalParekh I am a Java programmer and now I learn in Dartlang, but I don't know why the Dartlang's HashMap ```void clear()``` does not implement father class "abstract Map class". it's make me confuse because it is not the same as Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by reading the [Map documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map-class.html):

1. Built-in classes that implement `Map` are listed under:

   > Implementers
   >
   > HashMap HttpSession LinkedHashMap MapMixin MapView

   If you mean how do you know which derived class is instantiated by `Map`'s factory constructor, again, [the documentation says so](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map/Map.html):

   > `Map<K, V>` constructor
   >
   > Creates a Map instance with the default implementation, LinkedHashMap.
2. If you look at the [documentation for `HashMap`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html), it says:

   > *clear*() → void
   >
   > Removes all pairs from the map. [...]
   >
   > *inherited*

   It explicitly tells you that the `clear()` implementation is inherited from a base class.  If you click on it, it will take you to [the class that it inherits it from](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map/clear.html).